# Why aren't my Django app's model's Field values changing?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a basic Django app similar to the tutorial. I try to change the value of poll after it's been created and saved and I can't. I've tried using `.commit()` in addition to and instead of `.save()` and that didn't work either. Here's what it looks like when I try to change things from the shell. Similar results when through HTML (that is, failure). Any suggestions? I've tried changing the attributes of the fields in the models to `editable=true` which didn't cause any errors but also didn't help. Any ideas what could be going on here?

```
>>> from votes.models import polls
>>> polls.objects.all()[2].title
u'best band'
>>> polls.objects.all()[2].title='best album'
>>> polls.objects.all()[2].title
u'best band'
>>> polls.objects.all()[2].title='best album'
>>> polls.objects.all()[2].save()
>>> polls.objects.all()[2].title
u'best band'
```

Comment: you're retrieving the record from the database each time, without saving it after the change you've made. Grab a reference to it first, change that, then save it.

Comment: But i used `.save()`? I also tried `a=polls.objects.all()[2]` and then `a.title='blah blah'` and then `a.save()` and that didn't work either. Do you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `polls.objects.all()`, you get an array of reconstituted objects from the database - each time you call `.all()`, it reconstitutes them from the database again for you, creating a new copy. You're modifying one of these, but not saving the same one you modified.

What you're doing:

```
>>> from votes.models import polls
>>> poll = polls.objects.all()[2]
>>> poll.title = 'best album'
>>> poll.title
'best album'
>>> another_copy_of_poll = polls.objects.all()[2]
>>> another_copy_of_poll.title
u'best band'
>>> another_copy_of_poll.save()
```

What you ought to do:

```
>>> from votes.models import polls
>>> poll = polls.objects.all()[2]
>>> poll.title = 'best album'
>>> poll.title
'best band'
>>> poll.save()
```

Comment: Can you clarify? I've tried to explain it above with the two examples, but we're having trouble communicating something. Would a non-database example be helpful?

Comment: Awesome, sweet. Now I understand and it works. Two thumbs up!!

Answer (score 2):

To explain Thomas' comment.

Assign polls.objects.all[2] to a variable, then change the title attribute of that object and save that.

```
>>> poll = polls.objects.all[2]
>>> poll.title = 'best album'
>>> poll.save()
```